# Metro Apps Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, windows-8

quick question. I just downloaded Visual Studio 11 Developer Preview but all tutorials to try out Win 8 Development requires "Select the Windows Metro style template type." I do not see this as an option on my screen.

Do I need to download and install Windows 8? (Can I install windows 8 preview alongside Windows 7)?

Can I not try this out yet? Some clarification on how to get started would be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must have the Windows 8 Developer Preview to create a Metro style app. You can dual boot Win7 and Win8 though.

Comment: Thanks! for the answer - will download Windows 8 Dev Preview.